# Terraform data dynamically using variables

Tags: azure, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

I was wondering if it's possible to grab different data dynamically based on variables like so

```
data.terraform_remote_state.vm.outputs.vm_***var.vmname***
```

Or something similar? i dont have the option to redesign the outputs currently, and this would greatly lower the chance of making failure upon creating new terraform deployments

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are Input Variables available in Terraform.  These variables allow you to define inputs expected at the time of `terraform apply`.  The values may be entered via an interactive terminal or provided in a `.tfvars` file.

```
variable "vmname" {
  type        = string
  description = "The name of the virtual machine."
}
```

Then you can use them by expansion:

```
"data.terraform_remote_state.vm.outputs.vm_${var.vmname}"
```

For additional reference, see https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html